# Automatic language-culture selection and fallback algorithm in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internationalization

We are building a site that supports several languages.  We have created resources to support fr, de, and en-US with en-US as the default.  I have added:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization 
        uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" 
        requestEncoding="utf-8" 
        responseEncoding="utf-8" 
        enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

to my `web.config` file.  If I set the language to fr, de, or en-US in IE or Chrome, I get the expected language.  If I set the language to ar-EG, I get en-US, also as expected.

If I set my language  to fr-FR, but do not include fr in the list of accepted languages, the site returns the fr page, even if I tell the browser that I prefer accept de to generalized fr (as opposed to fr-FR).  This appears to be contrary to the RFC's, but is not surprising, because IE defaults to fr-FR in France and de-DE in Germany, and does not work with sites that do not automatically generalize the culture.

However, if I tell the browser that I accept ar-EG and fr, the site defaults to en-US -- even though the Accept-Language header specifies that I will accept fr with a higher priority.  I captured the request header in the browser to make sure all the languages I asked for were being sent with the right priorities.

It appears that ASP.NET is only ever looking at the first language specified in the Accept-Language header.  Is the ASP.NET language matching algorithm specified anywhere?  Is there a way to specify that ASP.NET/MVC should check all the languages in the Accept-Language list to determine the best one?  Or do I have to write my own language matching code?

Comment: "Is the ASP.NET language matching algorithm specified anywhere? " - yes, in MSDN it states that "To have ASP.NET set the UI culture and culture to the first language that is specified in the current browser settings, set UICulture and Culture to auto", exactly what you're seeing - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well, as nobody else answered yet, I make my suggestion. There is a better or at least more beautiful solution for sure, but for my needs it was enough. Just set the culture inside your `Application_AcquireRequestState()` event:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState()
{
    var language = "whatever"; // default fall back
    if (request.UserLanguages.Length > 0)
    {
        var acceptedLangs = new List<string> {"de", "en"};
        var langs = request.UserLanguages.Where(l => acceptedLangs.Any(al => al.Equals(l.Substring(0, 2))));
        language = langs.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    // TODO: may be better inside a try..catch block
    var culture = new CultureInfo(language);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
}
```

Comment: I think I will have to write my own, as you suggest, but your example is basically what ASP.NET is doing.  What I need to do is look at _all_ the languages in `request.UserLanguages`, parse out the quality values for each of them, and find the best match to the languages we support, using the RFC-specified rules.  It's not rocket science, just disappointing that the framework does not support the standard behavior.

Comment: @wrdieter, I updated my answer to just search for accepted languages.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it is more complicated than that.  Languages can (and often do) have "quality" specs, users can specify wildcard subtags, language tags can request a particular script style, etc.  RFC2616 lists the rules for the Accept-Language header, and BCP 47 (a combination of RFC5646 and RFC4647) describes more about language tags and how to match them.  It is pretty easy to write something that works a lot of the time, and a pain to always get it right.  I was hoping the framework would handle it for me, but the docs pointed to by Joe say it does not.